# Image search API (alternative to dicontinued Google Image search API)

Tags: gratis, images, web-services, search-engine

My app has a feature to easily add an image based on words you had typed. For instance, after you had typed "apple" it suggests an image of an apple to use as an illustration.

PROBLEM: My app was using the Google Images Search API, which got discontinued, and the legal status of the images was unclear anyway. Yahoo Boss API, which was doing the same, got discontinued too. I am looking for an alternative with clearer legal status.

Requirements:

- Given a word or string of words in any language, gives back a few images that match the word
- Provide the URLs to both a thumbnail and the full image
- All images are public domain (CC-BY-SA acceptable too if the legal mention to use is included to the response)
- Free to use
- HTTP or HTTPS-based API

If there is a daily limit, I prefer it to be user-based (X images per day per IP address) rather than API-key-based (Y images day for all users of my app)